# How to Join two Query in SPARQL python (sparql-client)

Tags: sparql, rdf, rdfs, rdflib

I am writing a **SPARQL** query to get name and expertise from 2 rdf files. Using rdflib graph() I can parse and query one rdf files at a time but I could not get the join ideas here. How can I do that? How can I parse two rdf files and make a join **SPARQL** query for example UNION in python client? please share your idea's. Thank you.

name.rdf

```
<rdf:RDF
 xmlns:researche="http://example.com/researche#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
 <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.app.web/researche#researcher1">
   <researche:name>John Snow</researche:name>
   <researche:hasExpertise rdf:resource="http://example.com/researche#expertise1"/>
   <researche:hasExpertise rdf:resource="http://example.com/researche#expertise3"/>
 </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

expertise.rdf

```
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:researche="http://example.com/researche#"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.com/researche#expertise1">
  <researche:name>Web engineering</researche:name>
 </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.com/researche#expertise2">
  <researche:name>DevOps</researchee:name>
 </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Here is my query.py file..

```
g.parse("name.rdf")
g2.parse("expertise.rdf")

qres = g.query(
    """SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?expertise
       WHERE {
          ?a researche:name ?name .
          ?a researche:hasExpertise ?expertise .
       }""")
```

N:B: the query.py is incomplete.

Comment: just merge both graphs and run the query on the merged graph: https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/merging.html

Comment: `g_merge = g + g2` then `g_merge.query(...)`

Comment: Thank you @UninformedUser I will do that :)

Comment: @MeshuDebNath can you please mark this Issue closed/resolved if the tip from UninformedUser worked? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have marked. thanks